# foundation-5 atmosphere package nav-bar expand-collapse does not work

Tags: jquery, css, meteor, zurb-foundation

I have added foundation-5 from atmosphere for meteor packages. When I put the following in my template for top-nav-bar, the nav bar does not expand and collapse on small screen. Can you tell me what am I missing here? I also installed scss running "npm install -g scss"

```
<template name="header_temp">
<nav class="top-bar docs-bar" data-topbar="">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#"><font id="Q">Q</font><font id="o">o</font><font id="ll">ll</font></a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right nav bar section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button with Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left nav bar section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second Left Nav</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Third Left Nav</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Following is the list of packages:

- standard-app-packages
- preserve-inputs
- observatory
- highcharts
- accounts-password
- google
- facebook
- oauth
- iron-router
- font-awesome
- HTML5-History-API
- observatory-apollo
- observatory-galileo
- page-js-ie-support
- inspector
- chartjs
- showdown
- jquery
- jquery-ui
- accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
- foundation-5

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, juat remove the foubdation-5 package and install zurb-foundation package. Its seems like the foundation-5 package is not working...